# ASP.NET MVC, C#, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to update supplier in database when users on webform insert data into textboxes.

First users in textbox for supplierID insert value, and on screen shows particular supplier from database. Then user can change supplier and when he is done he have to click on submit button.

I use `EntityState.Modifier`, but supplier doesn't change in database, and also I have no errors in the view. I think that's not working because my Supplier have foreign key from Adress table.

Does somebody know how to update using Entity state modified if a have a foreign key to another table?

I appreciate any help!

```
public partial class Supplier
{
    public int SupplierID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Phone{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TownID{ get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> StreetID{ get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AdressNumber{ get; set; }

    public virtual Adress Adress { get; set; }
}

public partial class Town
{
    public int TownID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Street
{
    public int TownID{ get; set; }
    public int StreetID{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Adress
{
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
public Adress()
{
this.Supplier= new HashSet<Supplier>();
}

public int TownID{ get; set; }
public int StreetID{ get; set; }
public int AdressNumber{ get; set; }

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<Supplier> Suppliercs{ get; set; }
}
```

This is my View:

```
@model FpisNada.Models.Supplier
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";

Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SupplierID, new { @placeholder = "pib dobavljaca", style = " float:left" })

<div class="col-md-9">
@if (ViewBag.ListTown!= null)
{
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TownID, ViewBag.ListTown as SelectList, "--select town--", new { @class = "form-control", style = " float:left" })

}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StreetID, new SelectList(""), "--select street--", new { @class = "form-control", style = " float:left" })


<div class="container">


@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AdressNumber, new { @class = "form-control"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, new { @class = "form-control"})
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Edit" />
}

My controller method:

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{

Supplier supplier= db.Supplier.Find(id);

return View(supplier);
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit( Supplier supplier)
{

try
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{

db.Entry(supplier).State = EntityState.Modified;

db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("ChangeSupplier");
}
}
catch (DataException /* dex */)
{
//Log the error (uncomment dex variable name after DataException and add a line here to write a log.)
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
}
return View(supplier);
```

}

Comment: Don't post **screenshots** of your code - **post your code** as text and **properly format it** (using the `{  }` button in the editor)

Comment: Thanks for help with formatting! I have trouble with posting code,but now i get it, thank's again! I edit screenshot with code. I hope somebody will help me with this issue.

Comment: Problem is most likely in your controller POST code. Show that and debug to make sure the model is correct before the database update code.

Comment: Thank's for reply and help!